# The text contained in the tag is equal to a specific text and does not contain only the specific text

Tags: python, selenium

Here is my probleme:
I have two tags.

```
<div class='twoLink'
<a class='link' <div> microsoft word </div></a>
<a class='link' <div> word </div></a>
</div>
```

My goal is to click on the tag containing only the word "word" and not "microsoft word".

so I did this :

```
element = 'word'
linkWord = WebDriverWait(driver, timeout=5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
         (By.XPATH,"//a[contains(@class, 'link')]/div[contains(text(), '"+ element +"')]")))
         driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", linkWord )
```

But this method makes me click on the tag containing "word" and not equal to "word", so the tag I click is the first one and not the second one as I would have liked.

I would have to find a method to check an equality but I didn't find one.

What can I do about it please ?

Comment: Your HTML is invalid (your `<a>`nchor tag is missing a `>`).

Comment: //a[@class='link']/div[text()='word'] which is simply f"//a[@class='link']/div[text()='{element}']"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//a[@class='link']/div[text()='word']
```

which is simply

```
f"//a[@class='link']/div[text()='{element}']"
```

Remove `contains()` and then just use `text()` to compare what the `<div>` tag value is.

Comment: thank you, it helped me a lot. But I added some modifications to make it work:
f"//a[@class='link']/div[text()='" + element + "']"

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way you can assert if the word is present.
I noticed that you are using contains because there is a space preceding the word `word` in element DOM, but `contains` is fetching the `microsoft word` since it contains `word` in in it. So, the below approach works. I have added asserts in a conditional statement to be clear, but you can actually reduce it to one line `assert x == 'word', "not the right word"`

```
x = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='twoLink']//following-sibling::a").text
print(x)
if x == 'word':
    print("True")
    assert True
else:
    print("False")
    assert False
```

Output:

```
word
True

Process finished with exit code 0
```

This also works:

```
//a[@class='link' and text()=' word ']
```

One more strategy would be to use `normalize`. Please research on that if you would like to use it.
Here is the normalized-space locator. This would find you your element:

```
//a[normalize-space(text()='word')]
```